# Series of natural numbers which has all same digits

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods

> For which $x$ exists sum $1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n$, where $n > 3$, which has notation $xxx\ldots x$?

In other words, I am looking for a sum of natural numbers which gives a result which has all same digits, e.g. $5555555$ or $22222222222222222$, or whatever else.

How to find this series and how to proof it for all possible series?

I have found the following examples:

- $1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + 10 = 55$
- $1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + 11 = 66$
- $1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + 36 = 666$

---

And what about next series which ends with (different) repeating $x$? Hot to find and proof it?

Comment: I want to proof how to find number which can be written in one same repeating digit. This number must be created from sum of natural numbers from 1 to infinity.

Comment: are you just looking for one point that this could maybe be true because it sure doesn't hold for the first such number 11 = 1+2+3+4+5 - 4... 22 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7 -6

Comment: I want sum (only addition is allowed)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55
the x = 5

Comment: looks like 55 works but you want to stop somewhere short of infinity to have a finite value.

Comment: the next one: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 = 66

Comment: The sum $1+2+...+n$ is $n(n+1)/2$, and I did a computer search on these numbers for $n$ up to $100,000$ and found no further examples than you have already in which all digits are the same (except for trivial cases of a few one digit sums). So a proof there are no more would be great if someone could give one!

Comment: Intuitively, the chance of an $n$ digit number having all digits the same is $10^{-(n-1)}$, so as you go up you expect them to stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that it is known that the only triangular numbers (i.e. sums $1+2+\cdots+n$) which are also "repdigits" (i.e. all the same digit in base 10) are, as listed in the O.E.I.S as sequence  [A045914](http://oeis.org/search?q=A045914&language=english&go=Search) those in the list
$$0,\ 1,\ 3,\ 6,\ 55,\ 66,\ 666.$$
As you see they are including $0$ (the "empty sum" of digits, or the $0^{th}$ triangular number.) They also include the single digit numbers $1,3,6$ since technically they are repdigits of only one digit, and are also triangular. Thus it is known that the three you mention are the only ones of length 2 or more.

In a related article/list  [A213516](http://oeis.org/search?q=A213516&language=english&go=Search) of triangular numbers with at most two different digits, in the discussion they refer definitely to the fact that the above list is complete for the one digit triangular numbers. Also at the first reference A045914 there is a citation of a paper by D. Ballew and R. Wagner which appeared in J. Rec. Math. Vol 8 (2) p 96, year 1975-76, titled "Repdigit Triangular Numbers". I don't have access to that, but perhaps in that paper they have a proof that the above list is complete.

Comment: Great answer.  You could make links to OEIS for the sequences you cite.  As you type the answer, you can click on the chain icon to insert a link.  It lets you put in a URL, then put in the text you want displayed.

Comment: Thanks Ross for the hyperlink tip... I found it, and tried it above in an edit. (Always wondered how that was done...)

Comment: Your links work fine-congrats.  As a style question, I would make the link text A213516.   Whatever you like.

Comment: @RossMillikan  I thought of that, too late. Can I now go back and change the names on the links? (Don't want to mess it up if that's not an option)

Comment: You can edit your post.  I have been faced with this.  I delete the whole bracket of the reference and the reference at the bottom, then put in new ones.  There may be a lesser work way to do it, but I don't know it.  I know this one works.  Good on you for making it better.

Comment: Thanks again, now it looks better with only the sequence numbers in the blue, "hyperlink" style, and they work fine. I'd never have caught on to how to change the names successfully.

Comment: And do you have any idea how the proof could be done? The book you mentioned is for me not available.

Comment: @Palmer No I've no idea about proof. I found one could get arbitrarily many digits from the ones place toward the left which are equal (but in each case there were more unequal digits after that), but no way to keep track of all the digits at once.

Comment: Maybe this is an approach Considering $$9n(n+1)=2d(10^k-1)$$, we can bound the fractional part of $\sqrt{9n(n+1)}$ : $0<$frac($\sqrt{9n(n+1)}$)$<\frac{1}{2}$. The fractional part is strctly increasing, so for large $n$ it has to be very near to $0.5$. It remains to bound the fractional part of $\sqrt{2d(10^k-1)}$ with $0\le d \le 9$ and $k\ge 1$.

Comment: @Peter Interesting approach, $n(n+1)/2$ is the triangle  number and $d(10^k-1)/9$ the repunit, so I see multiplying by $18$ gives your formula. I don't immediately see why frac$(\sqrt{9n(n+1)}$ is less than $1/2$ and increasing, (but will try to see that).

Comment: Consider the taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ and $\sqrt{9n(n+1)}=3n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: @Peter Yes -- see it now. I didn't notice anything simple numerically about the frac of the right side (yet), need to try more cases.

Comment: @coffeemath Good luck!

Comment: But it should be not too difficult to refute that the fraction is very near, but below $0.5$ for large $k$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer. I can't access to the article of Ballew and Weger, so I'm trying to prove this myself.

Let's say that $9n(n+1)=2dK_r$ where $K_r=10^r-1$ for $r\ge 2$.

**Some partial results**:

1. *The digit $d$ is $1$, $5$ or $6$*. Indeed, we know that $9+8dK_r$ must be a perfect square, so putting $d\in\{2,3,4,7,8,9\}$ and taking mod ${100}$ we get that 
   $$9+8dK_r\equiv9-8d\in\{1,93,85,77,69,61,53,45,37\}\pmod{100}$$
   There are only three quadratic residues mod $100$ in this list, namely $1$, $69$ and $61$, corresponding to $d=1,5,6$.
2. *If $d=5$ then $r$ is even*. Because if $r=2t+1$ for some $t\ge 1$, we get that
   $$9+40(10^{2t+1}-1)=4\cdot100^{t+1}-31$$
   should be a perfect square, but since
   $$(2\cdot10^{t+1}-1)^2<4\cdot100^{t+1}-31<(2\cdot10^{t+1})^2$$
   it can not.

**Some dead ends**

1. Taking mod $5^r$ for greater values of $r$ seems to be useless, because $9-8d=1,-31,-39$ are quadratic residues mod $5^r$ for every $r$.
2. The suggestion of @Peter about comparing the fractional parts of $A=\sqrt{9n(9n+1)}$ and $B=\sqrt{2dK_r}$, doesn't seem to lead anywhere. The fractional part of $B$ is difficult to control. Nevertheless, I have computed some values for $d=1,6$ and the distribution of the fractional parts of $\sqrt{2dK_r}$ does not seem entirely random.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the first n digits is given by $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and this must add up to repdigits in other words let the repeating digit be $x$ where $ x\in \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0\} $ then 
$$ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\underbrace{11..11}_{\text{k digits}}\times x$$
$$ n^2+n-\underbrace{22..22}_{\text{k digits}}\times x=0$$
$$\Delta = 1+\underbrace{88..88}_{\text{k digits}}\times x$$

Since $n$ must be a natural number $\Delta$ must be a perfect square. Therefor we are trying to find all the solutions to 
$$x=\frac{m^2-1}{\underbrace{88..88}_{\text{k digits}}} \text{ where } \{m\in Z|m>1\}$$

$\underbrace{88..88}_{\text{k digits}}$ can also be represented by $\frac{8}{9}(10^k-1)$, but I cannot tell if there is an arithmetic solution. With numeric methods I've gone up to 9 digits with no additional solutions. So regarding the upper bound what I can find is:

$$x=\frac{9(m^2-1)}{2^3(10^k-1)} <10$$

Using the quadratic formula $n=\frac{m-1}{2}$ simplifying to

$$x=\frac{9n(n+1)}{2(10^k-1)} <10$$ but i cannot yet find an upper bound for $m$, $n$ or $k$ using this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to prove this myself and found a quite elementary approach towards this problem which worked out to be really well.

Firstly, we know that,
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Now,
$n(n+1) = 2x(1\cdots1)$

This is quadratic in $n$, so, discriminant of the above expression is:

$1 + (8\cdots8)x$

This has to be an odd perfect square for $n$ to be an integer.

Rearranging the above expression,

$(8\cdots8)x = (m-1)(m+1), m \in \mathbb N$

Now, because $x$ only runs from $0$ to $9$, we can check the validity case by case.

Now, here’s the main **idea**. Clearly, $(8\cdots8)$ is even and equality of the form $(m-1)(m+1)$ is attained only when both the factors are even because $m$ = arithmetic mean of the two chosen factors. $(8\cdots8)x$ has only a handful of even factors (You can easily see why).

Now because $(m+1) - (m-1) = 2$, the two factors chosen should also have a difference of two (because arithmetic mean of the two numbers is equidistant from both the numbers and here, that distance is just $1$)

Let me do some cases for you:

1) $x = 1$,
$(8\cdots8) = 2(4\cdots4) = 4(2\cdots2)$,
As you can see, when the number of $8$s is 1,
we get $8 = 2\times4$ and this gives us $1$ as one of our answers and you can easily see in terms of the difference between the factors(which isincreasing with digits) that equality is never attained after this point.

2)$x=3$,
$3(8\cdots8) = 6(4\cdots4) = 12(2\cdots2)$,
As you can see, when the number of $8$s is 1,
we get $24 = 6\times4$ and this gives us $3$ as one of our answers and you can easily see in terms of the difference (which is increasing with digits) between the factors that equality is never attained after this point.

**QED**