# Find numbers of the form $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ such that the digits of the number are all same

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> Find all $a \in \{1, 2, \ldots, 8, 9\}$ such that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the digits of $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ are all $a$.

In other words, we have to find the values of $a$ such that $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} = a \cdot (1111\ldots1111)$ where $a$ is a Numerical Digit of Base $10$, i.e. $a \in \{1, 2, \ldots, 8, 9\}$.

I made the following progress:

Let's take $(1111\ldots1111) = R$ for convenience.
So we get the following equation: $n^2 + n - 2aR = 0$.
Taking the roots of $n$ by using the Quadratic Formula, we get $n = \dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+8aR}}{2}$ .

As $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $-1\pm\sqrt{1+8aR}$ must be even, so $\sqrt{1+8aR}$ must be odd and hence $1+8aR$ must also be odd.
We also know that $1+8aR$ must be a perfect square.

So, our problem reduces down to $1+8aR = f^2$ where $f \in \mathbb{N}$.

I couldn't proceed ahead from here.

---

[Series of natural numbers which has all same digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/588637/582927) also talks about pretty much the same problem. However, no conclusive solution was reached in that thread. I want to do the above question with an analytical approach. Hence, I beleive that my question is not a duplicate.

[Source: As far as I know, this problem is from IMOTC India]

Comment: Solve $$a = \frac{n(n+1)}{2\sum_{i=0}^{k}10^i}$$
for $k$ given a fixed $a$?... Good question...

Comment: Heuristically the only such examples are $0,1,3,6,55,66,666$ for $n=0,1,2,3,10,11,36$ respectively. (I just tested for $n\lt10^6$)

Comment: @Ahmed Hossam it's equivalent to: $2a(10^{k+1}-1)=9n(n+1)$

Comment: My method is identical to the one used by Pieter Rousseau here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1542564/582927. 

Is there any way I can proceed with a similar approach to prove that the following is true only for $a = 1, 3, 5, 6$? (not including $0$ because of the condition given in the question)

Comment: @Matteo of course, the formula for the geometric series. Ok, then you will get

$$a = \frac{9n(n+1)}{2(10^{k+1}-1)}$$

That is a very similar result to what Pieter Rousseau got at the end of his calculation. Plug in the possible values for $a$ and solve, then we get in fact nice results only for $a=1, a=3,a=5$ and $a=6$

Comment: In math contests you should be live to the possibility that neither the first nor the second approach you can think of will allow you to finish the question.

Comment: Anyway, if you edit the question to title to match with the actual contest question (i.e. which *digits* appear as the only digit of a triangular number), I would vote to reopen this. That question is different from the duplicate target, and has been conclusively answered here by Samuel Bodansky.

Answer (score -1):

Let $T_n$ be the $n^{th}$ triangular number.

Modulo $10$, $T_n$ is $0,1,3,5,6$ or $8$.

Clearly $8$ is not a triangle number.

Modulo $100$, $T_n$ is never $88$.

Therefore $8$ does not work, and the only solutions are
$1,3,5,6$ (as shown in the comments)

Comment: How did you draw the conclusion that $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \mod{10}$ can only be $0, 1, 3, 5, 6$ or $8$?

Comment: How do we become sure that $\underbrace{88 \ldots 88}_{\text{k digits}}$ for any $k$ is not a Triangular number?

Comment: As I said in the question, I am looking for a contest math oriented solution which relies more on analytical methods.

Comment: This answer doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @AdityaDutt It is certainly within high school contest  math technology to prove that $T_n$ modulo $10$ or $100$ is a cyclically repeating sequence, and the observations Samuel listed let you conclude.

Comment: Mind you, it could be better to relocate this answer to the duplicate target.

Comment: Samuel, looks like some cannot follow your simple logic. May be you need to spell out the sequence of remainders modulo $25$ for all of them to see. That period fits into a single line unlike that modulo $100$, and still suffices.

Comment: So in summary the methodology is this

Comment: 1) show that the triangle numbers have a period of 25 modulo 25, 2) show that no triangle number is 88=13 mod 25