# Repdigit triangular numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

**Problem**

> Find all the triangular numbers that, written in base $10$, has all
>   their digits the same.

**My work so far**:

I know that the solutions are $0$, $1$, $3$, $6$, $55$, $66$ and $666$.

My work on the problem is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588637/series-of-natural-numbers-which-has-all-same-digits/3311526#3311526).

I also know that the proof that there aren't any more solutions is an article of *Journal of recreational mathematics, volume 8* by Ballew and Weger, p. 96. The title is precisely *Repdigit triangular numbers*.

But I don't have access to this article, not even paying for it. As far as I know, it has not been scanned, and my local library has not it.

I'm very interested in that proof (or *any* proof).

Thanks.

Comment: doubling them would get near repdigits.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3309219/11619). Not much new information there. Only the piece of information that the repeating digit must be one of those appearing in your list.

Comment: May I know the motivation for your interest in *Repdigit triangular numbers*, @ajotatxe?  In particular, does this have a bearing on the problem of perfect numbers?

Comment: There is a link to that publication of Ballew and Weger (and a second publication by the same pair) at https://oeis.org/A045914. In case the OEIS goes away (perish the thought!) while mathstack survives, the links are https://sdaos.org/wp-content/uploads/pdfs/Vol%2051%201972/72p52.pdf and https://yutaka-nishiyama.sakura.ne.jp/math/repdigit.pdf

Comment: WARNING: the argument of Ballew and Weger appears to be fallacious. In particular, they claim to prove there can't be a square ending in an arbitrary number of fours and a one, but all those numbers are congruent to $1$ modulo $5$ and modulo $8$ and so by Hensel's Lemma they can be squares modulo any power of ten.